# Referencing movieclip within another movie in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, scrollpane

I was creating a drap and drop simple game, dragging and dropping an item from within a movie clip. All was working fine, but then I had to add more items so I created a ScrollPane and referenced the movie clip through that, now I need to rework how I pull reference that movieclip again.

The movieclip is exported so the scrollpane can bring it in...

before:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class shopping extends Sprite {

        public function shopping() {

            shoppinglist.Ketch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
            shoppinglist.Ketch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
```

Any help welcome... And hope this makes sense...

**Edit

Still really struggling on this, here is my code:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class shopping extends MovieClip {

        public function shopping() {

            var counter:Number = 0;
            var startX:Number;
            var startY:Number;
            var budget:Number = 25
            scoreText.text = 'You have £'+budget+' for your weekly shop';
            priceText.text = '£'+budget;


            ScrollList.Ketch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
            ScrollList.Ketch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);

            public function pickUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
                e.target.startDrag(true);
                reply_txt.text = "";
                e.target.parent.addChild(e.target);
                startX = e.target.x;
                startY = e.target.y;
            }

            public function dropIt(e:MouseEvent):void {
                e.target.stopDrag();
                if (e.target.dropTarget != null && e.target.dropTarget.parent == trolley){
                    //reply_txt.text = "Good Job!";
                    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
                    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
                    e.target.buttonMode = false;
                    //e.target.x = trolley.x;
                    //e.target.y = trolley.y;

                    if(e.currentTarget.name == 'Ketch'){
                        budget -= 1.25;
                        scoreText.text = 'You have £'+budget+' for your weekly shop';
                    }

                    counter++;
                } else {
                    //reply_txt.text = "Try Again!";
                    e.target.x = startX;
                    e.target.y = startY;
                }
                if(counter == 4){
                    reply_txt.text = "Congrats, you're finished!";
                }
            }

            ScrollList.Ketch.buttonMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain which is which? Like, is the movieclip "ketch" inside "shoppinglist" which is inside the document class "shopping"?

Comment: ketch is the movieclip I won't to drag which is inside shoppinglist. shoppinglist is pulled into the scrollPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is the little code that might help

var Gotparent;

var myobj ;

public function pickUp(e:Event):void
{

```
 myobj      =  (evt.currentTarget)

 Gotparent  =   myobj.parent;

 addChild(myobj);

 myobj.startDrag(true);
```

}

public function dropIt(e:Event):void
{
  myobj.stop();
  Gotparent.addChild(myobj);
}